# How to check with a code if Chromebook running on ChromeOS is set to erase data on sign out or end of session?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I need help to figure out if managed Chromebook running on ChromeOS is set to erase data on sign out. I searched everywhere and can’t find a good reference about it.  [Google Docs](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#DeviceEphemeralUsersEnabled) mention about this property DeviceEphemeralUsersEnabled.
I tried this snippet, but found it to be not valid: 
`chrome.enterprise.deviceAttributes.getDeviceLocalAccoutns( data => {…});`

Also, I tried this example:  `chrome.management.get(“DeviceEphemeralUsersEnabled”);`
and no luck there as well.

Does anybody know how to check with JavaScript if user is on device which is set to erase data on sign out or end of session?